# How to get the firmware (hex) file from a .ino file containing the code

Tags: arduino-ide

I currently have a `.ino` firmware file that I use in the Arduino IDE to program an ATmega328 micro-controller. I would like to get the file that the Arduino IDE uses to program the micro-controller.

Probably the IDE uses a hexadecimal (hex) file or something and sends it to the micro-controller through the serial.

How can I get this file being the only file that the IDE generates is the `.ino`?

Comment: These questions have been answered here before.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I removed my question (was not aware of what you wrote) ... if the question has already been answered, it should be marked as duplicate question (s).

Comment: I am getting .BIN file while using the above method in Arduino IDE.

Comment: I guess this isn't allowing to add another answer.  One approach is to use the "Export compiled binary" listed in the answers.  You can also have the build go to a more predictable (non-temp) folder/directory.   Edit your `preferences.txt` file and add the line `build.path=<folder for build output>`, specifying an existing folder to send the build artifacts to.  Your hex files will be in there the next check/build you run.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Preferences of the Arduino IDE; after `Show verbose output during:` check the box next to `compilation`.

Then when you compile you should get something like this at the bottom of the window:

```
...
...
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom  "/var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/arduino_build_635063/Blink.ino.elf" "/var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/arduino_build_635063/Blink.ino.hex"
Sketch uses 928 bytes (3%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

At the end of the third line from the bottom you get the `.hex` filename. In this case (on OSX) that would be `/var/folders/tp/grrlc56j3z7057f12_7f1_0r0000gn/T/arduino_build_635063/Blink.ino.hex`

Comment: Perfect, this I needed. Now if I send through the serial this .hex file to the microcontroller it will work as the UPLOAD of the IDE?

Comment: Click the checkbox next to it to get verbose output on upload. You can the see the command the IDE uses to upload. Just a hint. It uses the avrdude command line program for that.

Answer (score 9):

You are asking how to locate the compiled hex file. It's easy! Follow these steps:

1. In the Arduino IDE select `Sketch` > `Export Compiled Binary`. This performs a compile. Once complete, this command places a copy of the compiled `.hex` file into the directory of your sketch.
   [image: Export Compiled Binary]
2. Then either browse to the sketch folder or in the IDE select `Sketch` > `Show Sketch Folder`.
   [image: Show Sketch Folder]

This generates two hex files for the target micro-controller; one with the bootloader and one without the bootloader. These hex files can be uploaded to the micro-controller using a programmer such as the Atmel Ice or AVRISPmkII.

Comment: It only places .bin files in the sketch folder.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to get the file is:

1. Sketch > Export Compiled Binary
2. Wait for the compilation process to finish
3. Sketch > Show Sketch Folder

You will find an extra file in the sketch folder, which in this case will have a `.hex` extension. This is the compiled file which would normally be uploaded to the Arduino board via **Sketch > Upload**.

Note that the "Export Compiled Binary" feature is only available from Arduino IDE 1.6.5 and newer.